# How does one get from St. Thomas to the Virgin Gorda Baths?

Tags: us-virgin-islands, british-virgin-islands

My kids and I are staying in the US Virgin Islands (St. Thomas) towards the end of August.  The [rocks - Virgin Gorda Baths](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g147358-d147484-Reviews-The_Baths-Virgin_Gorda_British_Virgin_Islands.html#photos) look really interesting.  My kids have passports, and I'll have a rental car on St. Thomas, but I'm not sure what sort of ferry will get me to said baths.

A few questions about how to get there:

1. What ferry can I take to visit?
2. How much does it cost?
3. (And here, this is personal opinion for anyone who has been) Is it worth it?
4. Is there a car ferry / is it worthwhile to bring said car into the British Virgin Islands?  I'm renting with Budget, which says I can go to St. John, but don't know if BVI would be included.
5. What options other than ferry service exist?  Being price sensitive, I am trying to bring 4 people (2 adults 2 kids) for the "best value" method of transport, meaning that cost is an issue, but so is comfort and time.

Answer (score 1):

I can really only comment on item 3 since I was on a private sailboat in the BVIs so that's how we moved around, but I would say if you can figure it out, it is worth seeing.  The Baths and Devil's Beach are both beautiful and worth spending time at.  Bring snorkel equipment and food.  There is a bar near the entrance to the Baths, but I think it's pretty limited.  Have a great trip, it's a beautiful area!

Answer (score 0):

Here in the Usvi now, there were basically two options:

1. I could take a ferry, round trip, on Thursdays or Sundays, 8am out, 3pm return. Going rate was $80 for the ferry, plus $40 BVI entry free (cost of customs). For four people, that would be $480.
2. Alternatively, I can charter a boat for about $600, and take up to 6 people to all of the islands- Jost, Tortolla, and Virgin Gorda, on my schedule. Technically, the break even point would be at 5 people, but that value proposition is fairly compelling.